# COCOS2DJS - How to fullscreen game in win32

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-js

I'm testing out cocos2djs. Is there anyway that i can make it a fullscreen at the start of the game? I set my resolution policy to 720p. ( 1280 x 720 ).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I'm using version 3.0 full. In the file `./frameworks/runtime-src/Classes/AppDelegate.cpp` find this block:

```
#if(CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_WP8) || (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_WINRT)
        glview = cocos2d::GLViewImpl::create("Learn1");
#else
        glview = cocos2d::GLViewImpl::createWithRect("Learn1", Rect(0,0,900,640));
#endif
        director->setOpenGLView(glview);
}
```

And, change `createWithRect` to `createWithFullScreen`. Like this:

```
#if(CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_WP8) || (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_WINRT)
        glview = cocos2d::GLViewImpl::create("Learn1");
#else
        glview = cocos2d::GLViewImpl::createWithFullScreen("Learn1");
#endif
        director->setOpenGLView(glview);
}
```

Recompile, and there you go.

Obviously, you'll want to make sure you're referencing your game name, and not "Learn1".